# Can't install google chrome on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: google-chrome

The termial say's package `google-chrome-stable` needs to be reinstalled but can't find it in the archives. What do I need to do? I keep getting errors.

Comment: can you post the output of the error you've got please.

Comment: keeps telling me same thing over and over and it wont let open the software center either because of this..

Comment: could you please tell me whether its a 32bit system you're running on or a 64 bit? Also, copy and paste the output of the error which you see on terminal.

Comment: 32bit system 12.04

Comment: Do I need to reinstall the whole system?

Comment: not necessary. please refer in the answers

Comment: If it's just the errors after installing the .deb file running `sudo apt-get -f install` in the terminal should be enough which will resolve the unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall previously install one:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
```

For 32 bit OS:

```
cd /tmp && wget -c https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

For x64 OS:

```
cd /tmp && wget -c https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 1):

This stuff has the same or almost the same procedure.

- run an update

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- download the Debian file

  ```
  wget -c https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
  ```
- install the file using dpkg manager.

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
  sudo apt-get -f install
  ```

That should have you fixed with everything needed for Google Chrome installation on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try below;

Open a terminal (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following wget command to grab .deb file:

**FOR 32bit**

> wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb

or if you've already downloaded the deb file, navigate to the directory using `cd` & type the following command;

> sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb

Errors will display on screen. To fix it, run below;

> sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: Do I need to extract files

Comment: not necessary.. make sure that you've downloaded the proper `.deb` file to install and execute it using the command I've specified. This should work fine as I've installed chrome now on my 12.04

Comment: got the same answer as I did at the start

Comment: Do I save the files? Or open with? If so open with what?

Comment: if you're downloading via web, then save the file to a location.. if you're using `wget` it will save it to the place where your terminal pointer location shows. I'd recommend to save the file and then execute it with `dpkg` command

Comment: I have done this twice and still same thing? guess i"ll reinstall the whole Op. system.

Comment: I've done it both ways still same thing

Comment: you still did not answer to my comment question yet. It would be nice if you can completely copy the output of that error and update it under your question to assist you better. :)

Comment: ok here it is Unknow error '<type 'exception.SystemError'> (E: The package google-chrome-stable needs to be reinstalled, but i can't find it)